# Friend Invite System for iPhone

Tags: ios, social-networking

I am looking for information on how to implement a friend system within my iPhone app. The app is going to use a web server to check login's. So would the logical thing be to have the friend system setup through the web server as well? I am clueless on what I need to brush up on to be able to implement such a thing so any information/tutorials/open-source code/guides would be helpful to help me understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: You're gonna need a lot more than an app to set up a social networking site.  Also, you can send server requests with the NSURLConnection class.

Comment: This question is just... way too broad.  I can list about four or five steps off the top of my head, and several of them branch outward.  You need a web server, a way to login, a way for users to 'find' other's accounts to actually friend, you need the website to track it, and then presumably you need something that uses that 'friend' relationship.  Too much for a quick stack question!

Comment: It is very broad question indeed due to the fact that I am unsure where to start, or even research on how to setup such a structure. Thank you for your replies. I'll be looking into both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ask new users about their email (login) and passwords. Also let users to invite to your app his/her friends via:

1. Direct input of known email address.
2. Selection friend from iOS addressbook (you will also need an email there).

Then just take care of maintaining lists of friends' emails on server side (or both server and client side).